# send multiple emails to different users in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, email, oop

I fetch different IDs with request array:

```
  <label for="students" class="students">Students</label>
  <select name="students[]" class="form-control select2-multi" multiple="multiple">
  @foreach($students as $student)
     <option value="{{ $student->id }}" >{{ $student->first_name }}</option>
  @endforeach
 </select>
```

I am able to get the IDs correctly. Now the question is how can I through the request send Mails to the chosen Students(User)

I thought of a for loop, but I don't seem to solve it. 
Thanks guys

Comment: the front end shouldn't be sending the emails it should be backend that's sending the email. Please give more info.

Answer (score -1):

In the controller that is handling the form submission, you would loop through the selected users and then you would be able to use the [Mail facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail) to send emails through your current email driver.

```php
public function formSubmission(Request $request){
    $emails = $request->input('students');
    foreach($emails as $email){
        \Mail::to($email)->send(new EmailMessage());
    }
}
```

If you're wanting to find user's associated with that email first and pass that in to the Mail facade, then you would simply do a query and loop through those results as well.

```
public function formSubmission(Request $request){
    $emails = $request->input('students');
    $users = User::whereIn('email', $emails)->get();
    foreach($users as $user){
        \Mail::to($user)->send(new EmailMessage());
    }
}
```